# GTKMM: How to attach keyboard events to an DrawingArea?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I need to attach a keyboard key event to my Canvas that inherits from DrawingArea.

I already added these events on  'add_events()' in my constructor but after run it the key event doesn't responds, whats wrong?

```
Canvas::Canvas()
:m_dragDataRequestedForDrop(false), m_dropItem(nullptr),m_flag(false)
{
    add_events(Gdk::BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | Gdk::BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK | 
        Gdk::POINTER_MOTION_MASK | Gdk::KEY_PRESS_MASK | 
        Gdk::KEY_RELEASE_MASK);

    set_app_paintable();
    this->set_can_focus(true);
    this->signal_key_press_event().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, 
        &Canvas::onDeleteKeyPress));
}


bool Canvas::onDeleteKeyPress(GdkEventKey *p_event)
{
    bool m_eventHandlerFlag = false;

    if (p_event->type == GDK_KEY_PRESS && p_event->keyval == GDK_KEY_Delete)
    {
        m_eventHandlerFlag = true;
    }
    if(m_eventHandlerFlag)
    {
        std::cout << "Holi DEL" << "\n";
        //removeActiveElements();
    }
    std::cout << "Key pressed: " << p_event->hardware_keycode
        << "\n";
    return false;
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't even enter the callback? Because this code works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should place GtkDrawArea in GtkEventBox and then doing all that stuff from GtkEventBox. As far as I remember, this is happening because there are not these events for GtkDrawArea. One in stackoverflow explained that, but only with GtkImage.
I know, that GtkDrawArea in GtkEventBox works, because I am currently writing app that uses it (app is in c, but it should work for c++ too).